# Is it possible to use QT buttons on existing win32 GUI?

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have an existing GUI for Maya plugin written in VC++ (Win32 API). Now Maya 2011 is using QT and I want to change the Button and menu as per the Maya theme. My question is is it possible to make use QT buttons over Win32 GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. QtButtons depends of all the Qt libraries to work, so if you are not using a Qt application you cannot use QtButtons. In any case Qt uses internally the operative system libraries, in windows it will use Windows Forms so If you dont style the button you will actually see a normal windows button. I dont know if this answer your question. (I may have not understand the question properly, if that is the case please give me more information and I will try to help).